# LWJGL Keyboard Input Not Calling Method To Draw On The Display?

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL, and the problem is, I can't get a square to draw on the screen after calling the `addSqaure()` method in the keyboard input section. I moved the code from inside the `addSquare()` method to the update section just to make sure it actually works, and it does. It's specific to the keyboard method. When I press the <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, it just prints the text intended.

Here is my code.

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class MainClass {

    public static void initDisplay()
    {
        try
        {   
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
            Display.setTitle("sqaure addddder");
            Display.create();
        }
        catch(LWJGLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void initGL()
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    }

    public static void gameLoop()
    {
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            getInput();

            Display.update();
        }
    }

    public static void getInput()
    {
        while(Keyboard.next())
        {
            if(Keyboard.getEventKeyState())
            {
                if(Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)
                {
                    addSquare(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.7f, 1f);
                    System.out.println("Square was addedd at point.");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Square was not added.");
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    public static void addSquare(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
    {
        glColor4f(red, green, blue, alpha);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2f(200, 200);
            glVertex2f(300 ,200);
            glVertex2f(300, 300);
            glVertex2f(200, 300);
        glEnd();
    }

    public static void callJanitor()
    {
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        initDisplay();
        initGL();
        gameLoop();
        callJanitor();
    }
}
```

What is the problem with drawing squares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addSquare` method doesn't actually add a square, it draws a square once. It is only visible for one frame per space press because the key event that you are checking for only happens once, when the space bar is first pressed. If you change the body of your `getInput` method to:

```
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)){
    addSquare(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.7f, 1f);
}
```

It will draw a square each frame that the space bar is held down.

Comment: Its moments like these, that not only do I feel stupid, but I am also extremely thankful for your accurate answer. Also, was it easy to figure it out? Did it take you a second? Or did you read it and immediately know what it was?